# How can the Bergman space $L^2_a(G)$ of a complex open set $G$ be a subspace of $L^2(\mu)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

How can the Bergman space $L^2_a(G)$ of a complex open set $G$ be a subspace of $L^2(\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the area measure on G? If $L^2(\mu)$ is a space of equivalence classes of functions then how is $L^2_a(G)$, a space of functions, contained within it? Are we using shorthand for some sort of representation of $L^2(\mu)$ where we're only considering representatives of each equivalence class as those that are continuous? Is there a unique element of each equivalence class of $L^2(\mu)$ that is continuous?

Comment: What's your exact definition of the Bergman space?

Comment: @CameronWilliams the definition given in Conway: the set of analytic functions $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int\int_{G}f(x+iy)dx dy < \infty $

Comment: Whenever there is a canonical injective function $\iota$ from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, one may identify $x$ with $\iota(x)$ and hence pretend that  $X$ is a subset of $Y$.  This is the case here, by identifying each element $f$ of the Bergman space with its class in $L^2(\mu)$.  This is as injection since two analytic functions that are equal a.e. must in fact be equal. Incidentally this is precisely what we have in mind when we say that $\mathbb N\subseteq\mathbb Z$, as integer numbers are in fact equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers!

Comment: @Ruy so does this mean then any equivalence class that is an element of $L^2(\mu)$ contains at most one analytic function?

Comment: Correct.  Can you prove that $f=g$ a.e. and $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $f=g$?

Comment: @Ruy Apart from thinking further about extreme cases, it seems intuitively true and was my suspicion (see the end of my question) but was unsure if this is what wikipedia and Conway were getting at implicitly when talking about Bergman Spaces being subspaces of Lp spaces

Comment: Yes I read your question to the end.  However I noticed the discussion was not going in the right direction so I thought I should weigh in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obviously have $L^2_a(G)\subset L^2_c(G)$, where $L^2_c(G)$ is the space of *continuous* square integrable functions. Then $L^2_c(G)\subset L^2(\mu)$ in the following sense: There is an injection $j:L^2_c(G)\to L^2(\mu)$ such that for any $u\in L^2_c(G)$ the only continuous representative of $ju\in L^2(\mu)$ is $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Say $f\sim g$ if $f=g$ ae. Say $[f]$ is the corresponding equivalence class. It's not literally true that $L^2_a\subset L^2$, but it's clear that $$L^2_a/\sim\,\,:=\{[f]:f\in L^2_a\}\subset L^2.$$

And there's no real difference between $L^2_a$ and $L^2_a/\sim$.

**The Point:** It happens a lot that people say something about $X$ when they really mean $X/\sim$. You just have to get used to it...